# Rank matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Given the following linear system in $3$ parameters, above $\mathbb{R}:$
$$\begin{array}{l}x+ky+z=0\\kx+y+kz=0\\(k+1)x-y+z=0\end{array}$$
For which $k$ values for this system:

1. Is there a single solution?
2. There are infinite number of solutions?

I eventually, I came across this matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&k&1\\0&(1-k^2)&0\\0&(-k^2-k-1)&-k\end{array}\right)$$
but stopped, because I can no longer divide by numbers which include $k$ (because I don't want to assume $k$ is not equal to a certain number).

I'd be glad if someone could point me out on this.

Comment: Do you know anything about determinants and singular matrices?

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we get
$$x=-ky-z$$ plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$k(-ky-z)+y+kz=0$$ mupltiplying this out
$$y(-k^2+1)=0$$ can you finish now?

Comment: I am supposed to answer this by ranking a matrix

Comment: then calculate the determinant of the given matrix

Comment: I have yet to study determinants

Comment: the determinant of the Matrix is $$k^3-k$$ use the rules of Sarrus